# Powershell Module Function Scoping: Make function available to sub-module

Tags: powershell, module, scope

Powershell 7:

I've got 4 Powershell modules (*.psm1): Global, then Dev/Test/Prod.

Global contains a number of "helper" functions, then a main function (I'll call it Invoke-Main) that glues the helper functions together and provides the process flow.

Dev/Test/Prod contains settings specific to each environment.

All modules are in the $env:PSModulePath (...\Documents\Powershell\Modules\AppName[Dev/Test/Prod/Global]) directory.

Once I moved the modules into the PSModulePath, I removed the explicit Import-Module ..\path\Global.psm1 from the Dev/Test/Prod modules.

All functions in Global have [CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess)].  They all use an approved verb (I don't think that matters but see question #2 below.)
There is an explicit Export-ModuleMember -Function Invoke-Main at the bottom of Global.  This is the only function that is exported from Global.

Invoke-Main has a command line option -Env [Dev,Test,Prod] and a switch statement to import  the correct environment module.

Questions:

1. There is one function Add-FilesToRun in global that I would like available to the Dev/Test/Prod modules, but not available in the PS console.  Is it possible to make that single function in Global available to Dev/Test/Prod without exporting it into the PS console environment?
2. When I launch the PS console, many (but not all) of the helper functions used in  Invoke-Main are in the console environment.  Get-Command shows they are imported from Source: Global.  They are only the functions within Invoke-Main also with the Invoke-* verb.  Why would they be in the PS console environment when they were not exported from Global?

Comment: You can call another PS module with parameters  The parameter can be used to call a function.  So your child module can have a select statement and depending on the parameter list will call one of the function in the module.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand this comment.  The Add-FilesToRun function is not available to Dev/Test/Prod unless I explicitly Export it from the Global module, which then surfaces the function to the console.  This may be what I end up doing anyway, although this "pollutes" to PS console environment - there is no reason for the end user to invoke this function directly.  Since the Add-FilesToRun function is somewhat short, perhaps another solution is just to paste it into Dev/Test/Prod.  But this reeks of code replication.

Comment: Suppose you want to put 4 large functions in one PS module and want to call from your main PS module?  What I'm says is to have a module subroutines.PS1.  When you call the module you would use : subroutine -name functionA.  Then in main section of module you would have a case statement using parameter name and call the function FUNCTIONA

Comment: Sorry still don't get it.  You've got things reversed in the above comment.

Add-FilesToRun is a function in module Global.  
I want to call it in "sub-modules" Dev/Test/Prod.  
I don't want it available from the PS console.

For now I'm just exporting it from Global.  So it's available in the PS console.  For my end users it will be yet another of the 100's or 1000's of cmdlets or functions they never call or use.

Comment: If you have a function that is called by many other modules It has to be in a module that can be called from other modules.  I'm saying you may have more than one function like this and you can put all of them into a single module.